# Is dog name history in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

The new question [Why is "Blue" a traditional dog's name?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6613) pushes the limits of scope that is currently in place.  I can see valid arguments to allow this to be in or out of scope.  A meta discussion is probably appropriate at this time.

Comment: Related discussion: [Should questions about history/descent of pets be on topic?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/should-questions-about-history-descent-of-pets-be-on-topic)

Comment: Why do you think this is different from the earlier discussion and warrants another discussion?

Comment: @Zaralynda To me dog names felt to me beyond the history scope discussed in the related link.  I like the question (and Matt has now posted a great answer) but I envisioned potential questions of scope, and wanted to have better place to discuss it than in comments. The related question's accepted answer says "**some history**", this feels farther than that.  Acceptance of this question implies "**all history**" where quality, reference supported answers could be posted are in scope.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you think this question is not a regular history question. Can you put it into words other than "this feels farther than" some history. (in other words, why is this meta question not a duplicate of the earlier question)

Comment: @Zaralynda if you think the "blue" question is covered by "History" then, I must have been mistaken in my assumptions of potential scope conflict.  I don't have objects to closing it as a dupe.

Comment: I tend to agree that's covered by "history" too. :)